# Run Acceleo from Windows command line using Maven

Tags: maven, eclipse-indigo, acceleo

We are using Eclipse Indigo, Acceleo 3.1.3, Maven 3.0.3.

We have a large Acceleo code generation project in Eclipse that we run successfully.
We need to now run that same project via command line from a Maven project so that the code generation step can be run unattended via a job.

Can anyone share the steps on how to configure this keeping in view the versions we have? If anyone has a sample, that'll be great.

We have already tried available information on the web, but the steps there are for different versions and don't work for us.
http://www.obeonetwork.com/page/building-an-acceleo-generator, 
http://www.obeonetwork.com/page/integrating-acceleo-in-an, 
and other sites.

Thanks for your help.